# Xamarin Android - Binding Card.IO - Class cannot have multiple base classes

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, card.io

I am trying to bind Card.IO with Xamarin Studio. I am getting the error "Classses cannot have multiple base classes." The line of code is here :

public sealed partial class CardIOActivity : global::Android.App.Activity, global::IO.Card.Payment.IN {

Does anyone know the line of code needed in Metadata.xml to remove one of these base classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Odd; I would expect `IN` to be an interface...

Above the `CardIOActivity` declaration should be a comment providing the XPath expression to refer to the type. Using that as a basis, you can `<remove-node/>` the `<interface/>`:

```
<remove-node path="/api/.../class[@name='CardIOActivity']/implements[@name='io.card.payment.n']" />
```

Comment: Your comment makes me re-think the way I did the 2 things I did in the Metadata.xml file.  The first issue was a property in the class "A" was also named A.  The second issue was that a type or namespace "IN" does not exist in the project.  I thought the best solution was to rename the "A" class to "IN" but that seems to be causing issue.  I have now named the "A" property to "B" but now am left with the type or namespace "IN" does not exist...